# Are these integrals solvable?

Tags: calculus

These (shown in the video) are from a Calculus $2$ class, but they seem unusually hard.  I'm wondering whether they are solvable at all, or whether the professor just wanted to see if his students would be able to realize they are not.

They are here: https://youtu.be/pY9e09zMEZg

Comment: This is a joke of some kind.  The factorial, $!$, isn't even properly defined for all real numbers.  A real question would have the gamma function.

Comment: Even a typical high school student of calculus can immediately spot that these are absurd integrals.  Furthermore, having people click through to a YouTube video and waste our time watching this nonsense is offensive in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any of these can be solved using standard calculus 2 techniques, except #11 which can be solved with integration by parts twice:

$\int \ln^2x \ dx = x\ln^2x - 2\int \ln x \ dx = x\ln^2x-2x\ln x+2\int dx = x(\ln^2x-2\ln x+2)$

The rest either can't be solved at all, or involve special functions such as $\Gamma$, $\text{Ei}$, and $\text{Erf}$, for example. Integrating $x!$ -- or any composition thereof -- doesn't make any sense at all unless you tacitly assume that $x! \equiv \Gamma(x+1)$, since $x!$ is defined only for $x \in \mathbb{N}$.